# Why does creating database snapshot fail unless user is db_owner or sysadmin? MSDN suggests it should work

Tags: sql-server, snapshot

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) suggests that `CREATE DATABASE` permissions are all that is necessary to create a snapshot.

> Any user who can create a database can create a database
>   snapshot; however, to create a snapshot of a mirror database, you must
>   be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

This seems not to be the case.  When trying to create a snapshot via a user with this suggested minimal permission requirement, I get the following error:

```
Msg 1817, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
Only the owner of database "example" or the system administrator can create a database snapshot on it.
```

As I'd like to set up an automated process to create snapshots on a schedule, I obviously would like to avoid giving it `db_owner` or `sysadmin` rights.

Is it possible to set up as suggested by MSDN or are their docs wrong?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

```
/*as sysadmin*/

USE [master];
CREATE DATABASE example;
CREATE LOGIN testuser WITH PASSWORD='xxx'; 
CREATE USER testuser FOR LOGIN testuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;
go

USE [example];
CREATE USER testuser FOR LOGIN testuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=dbo;
go

USE [master];
GRANT CREATE DATABASE to testuser;
go


/*as testuser*/

USE [master];
create database example_snapshot_01
on (
name = example,
filename = 'C:\...\example_snapshot_01.ss'
)
as snapshot of example;
go


/*
Error:
    Msg 1817, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
    Only the owner of database "example" or the system administrator can create a database snapshot on it.
*/
```

Comment: Also. There's no difference in behaviour if `CREATE ANY DATABASE` permission is granted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to create a database snapshot, you will need `CREATE DATABASE` permissions as well as `db_owner` on the database you want to snapshot. I have tested this and it works perfectly fine.

The other solution is to grant `dbcreator` server role to the login that needs this privilege. This works too.

It seems that with `'Any user who can create a database can create a database snapshot'` this BOL means login having `dbcreator` server role.

Comment: Such a shame that `dbcreator` actually conveys create, alter, drop, and restore.